# React: useContext, how to retrieve it from an external component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

If I have in `Comp1.js`

```
const Comp1 = () => {
  const globalTheme = new createContext()
  return (
    <globalTheme.Provider globalStyle={anyVar}>
     <Layout>
      <AnotherComponent />
     </Layout>
    </globalTheme.Provider>
  )
}
```

And then in `layout.js`

```
  const globalStyle = useContext(globalTheme)
  console.log(globalStyle)
```

I get `globalTheme is not defined`, should I create the context again?

```
  const globalTheme = new createContext()
  const globalStyle = useContext(globalTheme)
  console.log(globalStyle)
```

Then I get `undefined` for `globalStyle`

what am I missing?

---

EDIT: Based on the comments, I use a third file and import the context to get access to it -> `theme-context.js`

```
import { createContext } from 'react'

export const themes = {
  light: {
    foreground: '#000000',
    background: '#eeeeee',
  },
  dark: {
    foreground: '#ffffff',
    background: '#222222',
  },
}

export const ThemeContext = createContext(
  themes.dark // default value
)
```

Then I provide this context in another file `blog-template.js`

```
import { ThemeContext } from '../context/theme-context'
import Layout from '../components/layout'

const Blog = () => {
let globalStyle = 'just any value'
return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider globalStyle={globalStyle}>
      <Layout />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
)}
```

And then in `layout.js`

```
import React, { useContext} from 'react'
import { ThemeContext } from '../context/theme-context'

const Layout = () => {
  const globalStyle = useContext(ThemeContext)
  console.log(globalStyle)
}
```

But `globalStyle` is undefined, why is that?

---

EDIT: The mistake was not to provide value as prop

```
-<ThemeContext.Provider globalStyle={globalStyle}>
+-<ThemeContext.Provider value={globalStyle}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `createContext` outside of the component and use the `Provider` with the `value` prop containing the data you want to be consumed further down the tree.

**Example**

```js
const { createContext, useContext } = React;
const GlobalTheme = createContext();

const Comp1 = () => {
  const anyVar = { color: "red" };

  return (
    <GlobalTheme.Provider value={anyVar}>
      <Layout>
        <AnotherComponent />
      </Layout>
    </GlobalTheme.Provider>
  );
};

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const globalStyle = useContext(GlobalTheme);

  return <div style={globalStyle}>{children}</div>;
};

const AnotherComponent = () => {
  return <div> Foo </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Comp1 />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's better to create the Context in a separate file so that you can export it and use it at multiple places, one of which being `useContext()` hook. This will anyways re-render when the data in Context changes.